# How to save a HTML variable in a PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I understand there's "POST" and "GET" to obtain data from a HTML page. Is there a way to obtain the variable from the HTML page, save it on the PHP page as another variable so the variable will still be there even though the PHP page is being refreshed.

Right now I can present the variable on the PHP page, but after I refresh the page it doesn't save it or if I open a separate tab using the same URL, the variable isn't there.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: you need to persist said value somewhere, either a database/session var, in the backend, or using localStorage/sessionStorage/indexedDB in the frontend

Comment: I'm not understed question, maybe http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

You can store HTML form variables to PHP session variables.
Here is a super basic example:

```
<?php
session_start(); // this needs to be called anytime your working with sessions (even before destoying them)

if(isset($_POST['your_form_variable'])) {
    $_SESSION['your_session_variable'] = $_POST['your_form_variable'];
}

// $_SESSION['your_session_variable'] will now persist through every page load 
// until you destroy it by using:
//
// unset($_SESSION['your_session_variable']);
// 
// and to destroy them all:
//
// session_start();
// session_destroy();
// $_SESSION = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['your_session_variable'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['your_session_variable'];
}
?>
<form method="post">
  <input name="your_form_variable" value="Some value" />
  <button>Sumbit form</button>
</form>
```